# What is the default datatype of "Front Matter" for a Jekyll site?

Tags: html, jekyll, yaml-front-matter

I'm working on a Jekyll website. What is the default data type of variables in the Front Matter? Is it a string?

```
---
layout: post
title: 
meta_keywords: key1, key2, key3
---
```

I'm trying to parse the keywords into an array and assign them to tags for each blog post, but I keep getting one long tag. I think I can use something like this?

```
<ul class="tags">
{% assign tags = page.meta_keywords | split:"," %}
{% for tag in tags %}
<a href="#" rel="tag">{{tag}}</a>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Frontmatter for Jekyll is YAML inside a markdown file. I suggest that you swing on by jekyll's gitter.im chat. They may be able to help you there.

Answer (score 1):

To create an array in yaml :

```
meta_keywords: [key1, key2, key3]
```

or

```
meta_keywords: 
  - key1
  - key2
  - key3
```

You can then loop

```
<ul class="tags">
{% for tag in meta_keywords %}
<li><a href="#" rel="tag">{{tag}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

See https://github.com/planetjekyll/quickrefs/blob/master/YAML.md

Comment: For SEO I've seen the keywords as a string in the yaml. Would it still work as an array? I was trying to save some back-pedaling in my post files by converting the string to an array.

Comment: For SEO you can use `{{ page.meta_keywords | join: ", " }}`